# how to Perform search operation in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am finding it difficult to perform a search operation on a html button event in Django.
My project is having a mobile database i am trying to search a mobile.

Comment: Can you please add more specific information of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you are having a button with id="resume", then you can invoke a particular Django view using the following sample code:

```
$("#resume").bind("click",function() {
    $.post("/resume/",
    {
        name: "Resume" //Any example parameter that is to be passed to the view function.
    },
    function(data,textStatus)
    {
    //Callback function on success
    });
});
```

And the example view function in views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def resume(request):
    //Do your search operation.
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The above code also needs jQuery library in your HTML code.